# how to get the time elapsed in the buffering state using youtube API?

Tags: android, youtube-api

please, i need to get the inital delay time and the buffering time and frequency from the Youtube API which i used to embed video in my APP. I have search but what i used to see is how to only use the API to play video but not to get the initial delay time and buffering frequency.

Comment: AFAIK, you can use the **`onStateChange`** then if it return `3 (buffering)` you can start your own counter to get the total time elapsed during buffering state. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rebot, but I will be glad if I can get the code